# Итератор для множества

Tags: c++

Какой `OutputIterator` используется для контейнера `std::set`?

Comment: В каком смысле «используется для»? Расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @VladD Хочу с помощью потоковых итераторов скопировать элементы из потока в контейнер `set`

Comment: А, для вставки? А [`std::insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) не катит?

Comment: @VladD ну я пробовал использовать `inserter(S)`, где `S` - имя контейнера - не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::inserter` вполне работает:

```
std::vector<int> from = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::set<int> to; 
std::copy(begin(from), end(from), std::inserter(to, begin(to)));
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/zJDUsv